# Finding the farthest point on ellipse from origin?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

I need to find the farthest point of the ellipse from the origin, I thought it should be on the $x$-axis but I don't know how to prove it. Maybe a point has a greater distance due to the Pythagorean theorem, for example, one value can cause a bigger distance because of its y value, etc. I thought that I have to calculate it from the formula but couldn't understand how. This is the formula of my ellipse:
$$
\dfrac{\left(x-3\right)^2}{25}+\frac{y^2}{16}=1
$$

This is the original image of the question, I need to get the farther point on the ellipse from the center of the moon (0,0) (origin).

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: **Hint.** Your guess is a reasonable one. What is that point's distance from the origin? If it is $r$, then the equation of the circle at that distance is $x^2+y^2 = r^2$. Can you tell if that circle intersects the ellipse in more than that one point? ETA: The first comment is well-taken. What are you studying? What do you know how to do? What is the distance formula? Etc.

Comment: farthest points on an ellipse are just the points on major axis, look at auxillary circle for example; the proof is that each point on ellipse can be written as (acosx,bsinx) so we wanna maximise $a^2cos^2x + b^2sin^2x=a^2-(a^2-b^2)sin^2x$ which because $a>b$ is clearly minimised for x=0 or 180 in which case points are $(\pm a,b)$

Comment: have you tried drawing the ellipse ? once the picture is drawn the answer is not very difficult

Comment: @Aditya_math: "farthest points on an ellipse are just the points on major axis"; that's not necessarily true for an ellipse that is not centered at the origin. For example, if the $25$ is replaced by $4$, the furthest point is *not* a point on either the major or the minor axis.

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, but OP must convert the picture into a proof.

Comment: The origin is also a focus of this ellipse. Find the closest point on ellipse from the other focus.

Comment: @BrianTung sorry, i midread the problem, i thought they meant origin of ellipse

Comment: Firstly thanks @AnotherUser for the warning, I will be more careful. And thanks to all the ones who are interested, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be an overkill for a problem in 2D with a simple geometry, where a graphical solution is possible, but one may use the Lagrangian approach here.  So you are trying to maximize the distance from origin, i.e. $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$, where $(x,y)$ are supposed to lie on the ellipse, i.e. $g(x,y) = (x-3)^2/25 + y^2/16 - 1 = 0$.  We form the Lagrangian $L(x,y,\lambda) = f(x,y)+\lambda g(x,y)$.  Constraint qualifications are satisfied for this problem, so the points of maxima must be critical points of the Lagrange function.  Therefore
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \partial_x L &=& 2x + 2\lambda(x-3)/25 &= 0,\\
 \partial_y L &=& 2y + 2\lambda y/16 &= 0,\\
 \partial_\lambda L &=& (x-3)^2 + y^2/16 -1 &= 0.
\end{aligned}
$$

- If $\lambda=0$ then also $(x,y)=0$ from the first two equations, which does not satisfy the third one.
- We can isolate $x$ in the first equation and $y$ in the third: $x = \frac{6\lambda/25}{2+2\lambda/25}$, assuming $\lambda/25 \neq -1$; $y=0$, assuming $\lambda/16 \neq -1$.  This is then substituted into the third equation.

  - When $\lambda/16 \neq -1$ we have $y=0$ from the second equation, $x-3 = \pm 5$ from the third, so $x=8$ or $x = -2$. The corresponding values for $\lambda$ can be computed from the first equation.  This gives us two critical points: $(x,y,\lambda) = (8,0,-40)$, and $(x,y,\lambda)=(-2,0,-10)$.
  - When $\lambda/16 = -1$, i.e., $\lambda = -16$, we get $x = -16/3$ from the first equation, and subsequently $y^2<0$ from the third, which is not feasible.

All in all, out of the two critical points, $(x,y)=(8,0)$ is furthest from the origin (point of global maximum). Here is the picture

[image: The feasible set for the problem with two critical points]

Answer (score 4):

The points on your ellipse can be parameterized by $x=3 + 5\cos\theta$ and $y=4\sin \theta$.  The squared distance from the origin is
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
(3 + 5\cos\theta)^2 + (4\sin\theta)^2&=&9+30\cos\theta+25\cos^2\theta+16\sin^2\theta\\ &=&25+30\cos\theta+9\cos^2\theta\\ &=&(5+3\cos\theta)^2,
\end{eqnarray}
$$
which is clearly maximized when $\cos\theta=+1$.  The corresponding point is $(x,y)=(3+5\cos\theta,4\sin\theta)=(8,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

Parametrization

$$ x=3 + 5\cos\theta, ~y= 4\sin \theta $$

Distance squared from  origin is

$$ \rho^2= x^2+y^2 =(3 + 5\cos\theta)^2 $$

Extreme $\rho$ s at $ \cos \theta = \pm 1, ~\theta =(0, \pi)$ which occur at

$$ y=0,~x= 3\pm 5 = (8,-2) $$

on $x$-axis.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is optima of $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ under the constraint of the equation of the ellipse, that we note $g(x,y)=0$. Optima are reached at points where the gradients of both functions $f$ and $g$ are collinear. Doing the algebra, one finds the equation $y\cdot(3x+16)=0$. So indeed, you have optima for $y=0$ but also for $x=-16/3$. However, the second case yields non real complex solutions.

The farthest point from the origin on the ellipse is thus (8,0).